# I would like to count stocks that have price of 0 or null

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables:

table1: stock_list

```
Stock_name  Year    Qty Reserve
stock1  2015    1   0
stock1  2016    1   1
stock1  2016    1   0
stock1  2016    1   0
stock2  2015    1   0
stock2  2015    1   0
stock2  2015    1   0
stock2  2016    1   1
stock2  2016    1   1
stock2  2016    1   0
```

The second table is: products

```
Variant MY  List_Price
stock1  2015    2000
stock1  2016    0
stock2  2015    3000
stock2  2016    NULL
stock3  2016    4000
```

The result I am looking for is this table:

```
Name    Year    Qty Reserved    List_Price
stock1  2016    3   1   0
stock2  2016    3   2   Null
```

Is there a way to reach this result with a one MySQL statement.

Comment: I tried with many tries, none of them worked.

Comment: then also post your tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    Select S.Stock_Name as Name, S.Year, sum(S.Qty) as Qty, sum(S.Reserved) as Reserve, P.List_Price
    from stock_list S inner join products P
    on S.Stock_name=P.Variant and S.Year=P.MY
    where P.List_Price=0 or P.List_Price is null
    group by S.Stock_Name, S.Year, P.List_Price
```

Comment: It's close but I need to count the quantity

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT sl.stock_name,
       sl.year,
       sum(sl.qty) AS qty,
       sl.reserve
FROM stock_list AS sl
JOIN products AS p ON sl.stock_name=p.variant
WHERE p.listprice IS NULL
  OR p.listprice=0
GROUP BY sl.stock_name
```

Comment: The problem is my primary key is (Variant and Year) because I have stock1 2015 and stock1 2016 also I have stock2 2015 and stock 2016 and so on.